# Run Bash Command from PHP

Tags: php, bash, exec

I have a bash script, that I run like this via the command line:

```
./script.sh var1 var2
```

I am trying to execute the above command, after I call a certain php file.

What I have right now is:

```
$output = shell_exec("./script.sh var1 var2");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

But it doesn´t work. I tried it using `exec` and `system` too, but the script never got executed.

However when I try to run `shell_exec("ls");` it does work and `$output` is a list of all files.

I am not sure whether this is because of a limitation of the VPS I am using or if the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: What path are you running it in? What does `pwd` return?

Comment: Is your script executable by `apache` or `www-data` user?

Comment: Is that bash script in the same directory as your PHP script? Is the php script's working directory that same directory as well?

Comment: Does your script have an appropriate interpreter header, and can you run it manually from your terminal? Like: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Does it work with `shell_exec('sh script.sh')`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 1)I can run it from terminal. 2) @DanLee Doesnt work. 3)It seems that the php file I am modifying is a shortcut, because allthough I "see" them in the same dir, `pwd` did return another dir. Is it possible to include the path in the command?

Comment: Instead of `./script.sh` use `/path/to/script.sh`.

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  I can execute the bash script from both my home dir, and the /var/www/html/ dir.  When I run the <php> page, with 'LS' in the the exec('ls') it lists the files in the directory ... but when i put the bash file and path it doesn't work.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You probably need to [chdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to the correct directory before calling the script. This way you can ensure what directory your script is "in" before calling the shell command.

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/my/path/');
$output = shell_exec('./script.sh var1 var2');
chdir($old_path);
```

Comment: I think this did the trick! At least I got it working with a simple test script. To finally verify it, I have to wait for the server hoster to let me know the exact path to the scripts. I am gonna mark the answer now nevertheless. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrej: Or use the absolute path to your script instead of a relative one.

Comment: @Andrej If you're running PHP 5.3, you can use `chdir(__DIR__)` to change the directory to the directory containing the script. Or for PHP 5.2 or less, `dirname(__FILE__)` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks guys! It is working now. There has appeared a [new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053452/php-run-bash-script-to-create-file), but this one is solved ;)

Comment: If you want to be pithy swap `shell_exec` out for the [backtick operator](http://devdocs.io/php/language.operators.execution).

Answer (score 5):

Your shell_exec is executed by www-data user, from its directory.
You can try

```
putenv("PATH=/home/user/bin/:" .$_ENV["PATH"]."");
```

Where your script is located in */home/user/bin*
Later on you can

```
$output = "<pre>".shell_exec("scriptname v1 v2")."</pre>";
echo $output;
```

To display the output of command. (Alternatively, without exporting path, try giving entire path of your script instead of just ./script.sh

Comment: It's a unnecessary to alter the `PATH` environment variable. The current working directory should be changed instead (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11052453/24950)).

Comment: True. Thanks. I was using the path settings in my code because I have various custom executables in more than one locations, and I wanted the input box to work as a console, so I can invoke any command from those. If it is to be used for just single file execution, we can anyway just use shell_exec('/entire/path/to/file/');

Answer (score 0):

Check if have not set a open_basedir in php.ini or .htaccess of domain what you use. That will jail you in directory of your domain and php will get only access to execute inside this directory.