# Run bash script to create file in PHP

Tags: php, bash, exec

In addition to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php/11052453#comment14460416_11052453), another problem appeared and I decided to make a new question for it:

I am currently calling a php script that than runs a bash script. The php script looks like:

```
chdir('/home/');
$output = shell_exec('./do.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

The do.sh contains:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo 12;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.test bs=1048576 count=2
```

The problem is following:

When I call `./do.sh` from the terminal everything works fine: test.test is created and the ouput is `12`

However, when I call it from my php file, the output is `12` aswell, but **no** file is being created. Since I know almost nothing about bash scripting, I have no idea why this is happening...

Comment: That would probably be because the user that PHP is running as does not have write permissions on the `/home/` directory. You will have to `chmod nnn /home` where `nnn` is the appropriate permissions structure - remember to make it as restrictive as possible. You might want to look at the ownership and group memberships to get the best setup. To test you can `chmod 777 /home`, and if it works then you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did forget to put the correct permissions for the home folder. I only thought about the actual php file and changed its permission, but didnt do the same for the folder it is in! I hope you dont mind me marking @dAm2K ´s answer, since he also suggested to look at the permissions!

Comment: I upped its comment! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if PHP safe_mode is enabled. You have to turn it off in your /etc/php.ini file, and obviously check filesystem permissions.

Comment: Safe mode is off and the php aswell as the .sh file have all permissions to write. However, I am not sure about the user(see @DaveRandom ´s comment).

Comment: Try to use absolute path for dd: /bin/dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.test bs=1048576 count=2

Comment: It was the permissions after all! Thanks a lot! I did forget to put the correct permissions for the home folder. I only thought about the actual php file and changed its permission, but didnt do the same for the folder it is in!