# Detect if cPanel / WHM is currently running, in PHP?

Tags: php, backup, cpanel, whm

I have full automatic backups running fine in WHM, and I'm now implementing a script to automatically download content to a database, however they're not playing nicely together.

There's several dozen feeds I'm trying to aggregate, many of them containing several thousand items, so ideally I'd like this a process running round the clock refreshing them all, which alone isn't a problem.

But, due to the feeds and backups needing a lot of disk usage, the load and I/O wait time is getting ridiculous, so I'm hoping there's a way I can detect (preferably in PHP) if a backup is currently running pause the feed processing while that's happening.

I could just play around with backup/feed times so they don't coincide, but the backups seem to take anything from 2 - 10 hours, so that's really not ideal.

Can I detect if a backup is currently being run by WHM? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the name of the backup process shown when you type `top` using `SSH`, then I think you can use `ps aux | grep your_process_name` with `BASH` using `SSH`.

You may also call this commands using PHP , more info about this : [Run Bash Command from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php)