# Php webpage can not find bash file

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, shell-exec

I was following the guide written here [Run Bash Command from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php/11052453#11052453)

and I have /var/www/test.php

```
<?php $old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/home/');
$output = shell_exec('./test.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
chdir($old_path); ?>
```

and located by using sudo nano /home/test.sh

```
#/bin/bash
mystring="Hello World"
echo "$mystring"
```

yet running locally `http://localhost/test.php` I get a blank page.
I can run the file from the terminal, and I can run shell_exec('ls') successfully as php script, can anyone see what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: you are not echoing your $output `echo $output;`

Comment: right, following up on @ChristopherMorrissey either directly call shell_exec or output the `$output`

Comment: ok sorry that was a typo... updated the OP and I still have a blank page :(

Comment: And what happens if you just try the shell_exec command directly?

Comment: ahh permission denied... i need the chmod 700 ./test.sh i believe

Comment: hmm ran chmod +x /home/test.sh and that now produces Hello World in the terminal.. but web page still blank...

Comment: echo shell_exec('pwd')....maybe its the file location problem

Comment: I have identical code up on my server and it prints out "Hello" not "Hello World" so that a separate issue i'll look into but strange my local computer does not like it... is there some chmod I may have done on my local pc to cause it to behave this way??

Comment: ahh yes that gave me a blank after I am supposed to have gone to /home  tried ./home and that not working... is this a set chmod -x /home command time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem was resolved after a few typos and permissions not being set, but main problem it would seem is the getcwd() does not run on my OS locally or on the server... both Ubuntu 12.04

So for anyone else stuck with problems be sure to:

- Check the File can be executed via the terminal, if not run `chmod +x /file/location/test.sh`
- next check what directory you are in and moving to using the `echo shell_exec('pwd')`
- If you are not moving directory then try replacing the `getcwd()` with `dirname(__FILE__);`

This resolved the issues for me :) now to ty passing variables into that script from the php page!! Many thanks for all your help everyone.

`