# PHP script to execute a bash script

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have 3 scripts (I have removed the help_page function from the networkstats.sh script when I pasted here to save some space):

api3.php

```
<?php

output = shell_exec('/bin/bash /usr/share/nginx/status/getnetworkstatsin.sh');
echo $output;

?>
```

getnetworkstatsin.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i /tmp/id_rsa1 root@centos7clone bash -s -- -I < ./networkstats.sh
```

networkstats.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

interface=enp0s3

read -r inbytesold outbytesold < <(awk -v dev="^$interface:" '$1 ~ dev {
              sub(/[^:]*:/,""); print $1, $9; exit }' /proc/net/dev)

sleep 1

read -r inbytesnew outbytesnew < <(awk -v dev="^$interface:" '$1 ~ dev {
              sub(/[^:]*:/,""); print $1, $9; exit }' /proc/net/dev)

kilobitsin=$(( ( ( inbytesnew - inbytesold ) * 8 ) / 1024 ))

kilobitsout=$(( ( ( outbytesnew - outbytesold ) * 8 ) / 1024 ))

show_outgoing() {
echo $kilobitsout
}

show_all() {
echo "kilobits in: $kilobitsin"
echo "kilobits out: $kilobitsout"
}

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]];
then
        help_page
        exit 1
fi

for arg in "$@"
 do
        case $arg in
                -h|--help)
                help_page
                ;;

                -I)
                show_incoming
                ;;

                -O)
                show_outgoing
                ;;

                -A|--all)
                show_all
                ;;
        esac
 done
```

The problem I have is that when I execute the api3.php script from console, it is able to execute and return a value.

However when I try and execute from a webpage it fails to return anything.

I believe it is not even executing when I load it via the webpage by navigating to localhost/api3.php. Can someone help, what is the reason behind this? I have added

```
nginx ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/share/nginx/status/getnetworkstatsin.sh
```

To my visudo section, I have tried to change permissions of all files involved to 777 (temporally) without success.

EDIT: I should also mention that all these scripts are located inside /usr/share/nginx/status which nginx has access to.

Comment: is `output = shell_exec(...)` a typo? It should be `$output = ...`, otherwise you're trying to assign a value to a constant.

Comment: Plus, if you're running this via a webserver, then the webserver ID is **EXTREMELY** unlikely to have access to the `/root` dir to get at the root user's key chain, and allowing remote root login via ssh is a major security risk in any case.

Comment: hi @MarcB all the scripts are for testing purposes and all locked down via firewall. The nginx server is not public

Comment: well, I forgot to move the id_rsa1 file, I thought I had. I will try after moving it and report back

Comment: Still no resolve after I moved the id_rsa1 file out of root and managed to execute the script as nginx and login

Comment: found this question which might provide an answer to your problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php)