# From PHP a Simple Linux Script to return "Hello World"

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

Okay, happy to accept down votes to get to the bottom of my problem.   I am brand new to Linux but have hosted my PHP based site on a Linux cloud server and need to run a FFMPEG script to convert a video.  Under windows I have the full application working but under Linux I can't seem to get a basic script working and was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.   I have read the myriad posts on this, for example, [Run bash Command from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php/11052453#11052453) but it does not help me get to the bottom of it.

Here is what I have so far.

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('videos/');
$new_path = getcwd();
echo('newpath '.$new_path); <-- this outputs 'old_path/videos'
$temp=  shell_exec('./testScript.sh');
echo ($temp) <-- produces nothing
```

Test script ***testScript.sh*** is in the video directory and is simply

```
echo "hello world"
```

Thanks...

Comment: Where is videos located? Can you not `chdir('../videos')`?

Comment: I think that is the problem it is in the web root directory and probably should not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In shell script must write and the interpretator.

Try this: shell_exec('php ./testScript.sh');

Edit: change php with correct interpretator (bash, sh...)

Comment: Interesting - yes that fixed it.  I am intrigued as to why this solution has not featured in other posts on the this topic.

Comment: usually interpreter written in shell script. for example #!/bin/sh (first line in file)

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is check that PHP will actually allow to run an a shell script.

Run the following at the command prompt

```
php -i | grep disable_functions
```

This should reply with a line that looks like this

```
disable_functions => no value => no value
```

But if it returns a string that includes shell_exec, like this (it may contain other content)

```
disable_functions => shell_exec => shell_exec
```

Then you will not be able to continue.
The trick at this point is to try a local php.ini file and see if you can turn the offending directive off.

To do this copy the php.ini file to the directory you are working in.  Find the disable_functions => shell_exec => shell_exec line remove shell_exec.

then run you script on the command line like this

```
php -c php.ini myscript.php
```

However this may all be very restricted on a cloud hosting environment because access to the shell could obviously create a certain amount of chaos.

You can also do this with apache config and .htaccess.

If all the above is OK then check the permissions of testScript.sh and that it is set as executable.  To do that is

```
chmod +x testScript.sh
```

Sadly for you my bet is that the restricted cloud server environment will stop you.

Comment: It turned out that it was a matter of not specifying the interpreter, but thanks for this insight on some of the PHP internals.

Answer (score 2):

**File System Permissions**

It is likely that in your case the script is not executed due to insufficient [file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions). In Linux, you are allowed to execute a file by just writing a path to the file, if the file has executable bit set for the current user, or the user's group, e.g.:

```
~/scripts/abc.php
./script.sh
```

Otherwise, you should pass the file as an argument for appropriate program, e.g.:

```
php ~/scripts/abc.php
/usr/bin/php ./script.php
bash ./script.sh
```

You can check the file system permissions with `ls`, or `stat` commands, for instance:

```
$ stat --format='perm: %A | user: %U | group: %G' 1.sh
perm: -rwxr-xr-x | user: ruslan | group: users

$ ls -l 1.sh
-rwxr-xr-- 1 ruslan users 1261 Nov 26 11:47 1.sh
```

In the example above, executable bits are set for user `ruslan` and for group `users`, but not set for *others* (`r--`). The others are allowed only to *read* (`r`) the file, but not to execute, or write to the file.

To set the executable bits use `chmod` command, e.g.:

```
# For the user
chmod u+x file.sh
# For the group
chmod g+x file.sh
```

**A better control over the command execution**

The `shell_exec` function returns the contents written to the standard output descriptor. It returns `NULL`, if the command prints nothing, or fails. For example:

```
$out = shell_exec("ls -l inexistent-file");
var_dump($out); // NULL
```

So you have no good control over the error conditions with `shell_exec`. I recommend using `prop_open` instead:

```
$cmd = 'ls -l 1.sh inexistent-file';

// Descriptors specification
$descriptors = [
  1 => ['pipe', 'w'], // standard output
  2 => ['pipe', 'w'], // standard error
];

// Open process for the command
$proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);
if (!is_resource($proc))
  die("failed to open process for $cmd");

if ($output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1])) {
  echo "output: $output\n";
}
fclose($pipes[1]);

if ($errors = stream_get_contents($pipes[2])) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "Errors: %s\n", $errors);
}
fclose($pipes[2]);

// Close the process
if (($status = proc_close($proc)) != 0)
  fprintf(STDERR, "The command failed with status %d\n", $status);
```

**Shebang**

Consider using [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for the executable scripts. Examples:

```
#!/bin/bash -
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight this has given me on Linux.  Very helpful indeed.

Comment: Using your proc_open command I was able to discover that ffmpeg is returning 'Permission denied' however even setting all the privileges/permissions  to 744 ffmpeg will still not execute.

Comment: @TrueBlue, can you show the code? Otherwise, it's difficult to guess.. By the way, `set -x` command in Bash turns on debugging mode (you can see the commands being executed.

Comment: I suspect it is my incompetence.  The set -x was useful in telling me that the ffmpeg was not found, so I suspect that simply copying a linux executable onto a web server is not allowed

Comment: @TrueBlue, yes, you should install `ffmpeg` package on the server from  repository. For example, on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`; on Fedora: `sudo yum install ffmpeg`.

Comment: Well I have acquired a little more Linux knowledge over the past day or so thanks to your help.   I finally have it all working now and under my CentOS 6 distribution.  The key was getting the repository, once I had that the installation went without a hitch.   Although this is not part of the initial question, for anyone else with the same issue installing FFMPEG a step by step process is here http://www.crucialp.com/resources/tutorials/server-administration/how-to-install-ffmpeg-centos-rhel-redhat-enterprise-easy-way/