# php shell_exec can run command but not sh file

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

from PHP I can run commands with shell_exec but can't run bash files

I run this command

```
 sudo ls /var/www/
```

and i get results

```
 /var/www/1.sh 
 /var/www/2.sh 
 /var/www/3.sh
```

but when I run this command nothing happens

```
 $output = shell_exec('sudo sh /var/www/1.sh > /dev/null 2>&1');
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

In 1.sh i added this code

```
   #!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/echo "test" > TEST1.txt
```

it works when i type in terminal ./1.sh so only from php is not working

Server: centos
from PHP I think I have root premission to execute commands

Comment: So what does your php error log file say wht is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Bash Command from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will fix ur problem

```
$output = shell_exec('sudo /usr/bin/sh  /var/www/1.sh > /dev/null 2>&1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bash script has output into the TEST1.txt file, not into console!

Try that:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/echo "test"
```

Or like that

```
$output = shell_exec('sudo sh /var/www/1.sh 2>&1');
echo "<pre>" .file_get_contents('/var/www/TEST1.txt'). "</pre>";
```

That string are wrong!!!!

> $output = shell_exec('sudo sh /var/www/1.sh 2>&1');

`&1` don't have a reason, because don't have definition

> $output = shell_exec('sudo sh /var/www/1.sh > /dev/null 2>&1');

In this case `&1` === `/dev/null`

Comment: is not writing  to test1.txt thats the problem

Comment: I think trouble is: you are do not define path to test1.txt: echo "test" > /var/www/TEST1.txt

Comment: defined path but is same problem. if u run from terminal ./1.sh it create text1.txt but from php if i try to run 1.sh   text1.txt is not created

Comment: Okey. May be user `www-data` (apache2 server) don't have a write permission to the `/var/www` (or where you are save test1.txt) directory?